# iOS HTML parse issue

Tags: html, ios, parsing, tags, html-parsing

I have implemented HTMLParser to my project. I am connecting to a billing web site to my cell operator, and I need parse different variables.

From [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) content

I need get one tag that giving me an indication if the username and password were not OK and show an alert to users.

```
NSArray *spanNodes = [bodyNode findChildTags:@"div"];

for (HTMLNode *spanNode in spanNodes) {
    if ([[spanNode getAttributeNamed:@"class"] isEqualToString:@"notification-item notification-item-error"]) {
        //Above my tag
        [self alertMessageLogin];
        NSLog(@"%@", [spanNode rawContents]); //Answer to second question
    }
    else {
        NSlog(@"You are not logged in");
    }
}
```

But if I add else to this code, so I need check else no tag "notification-item notification-item-error", so show me another view.

In my case, after `if`, my code is going to `else` from some reason, so my code think that the `if` condition is false and going to the `else` condition. But without `else` all is working fine. Here is my log from `else`. I don't know, why is it printing a few "You are logged in"?

How do I fix this issue?

```
2013-04-09 23:48:50.828 GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in
2013-04-09 23:48:50.830 GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in
2013-04-09 23:48:50.830 GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in
2013-04-09 23:48:50.830 GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in
2013-04-09 23:48:50.830 GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in
2013-04-09 23:48:50.831 GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in
2013-04-09 23:48:50.831 GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in
2013-04-09 23:48:50.831 GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in
2013-04-09 23:48:50.832 GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in
2013-04-09 23:48:50.832 GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in
2013-04-09 23:48:50.832 GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in
2013-04-09 23:48:50.833 GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in
2013-04-09 23:48:50.833 GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in
2013-04-09 23:48:50.833 GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in
2013-04-09 23:48:50.833 GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in
2013-04-09 23:48:50.834 GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in
2013-04-09 23:48:50.834 GolanTelecom[90143:c07] <div
class="notification-item notification-item-error"><div
class="notification-item-inner"><span
class="notification-content">???? ???? ?? ?????
??????</span></div></div> 2013-04-09 23:48:50.834
GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in 2013-04-09 23:48:50.835
GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in 2013-04-09 23:48:50.835
GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in 2013-04-09 23:48:50.835
GolanTelecom[90143:c07] You are logged in
```

Comment: The code with `else` branch will be helpful.

Comment: Hi A-Live I have added else to my example

Comment: I can't neither NSLog for `You are logged in` nor log messages `You are not logged in`. It will be pretty hard to understand what's wrong with incomplete code. You might want to try logging (or watching) the value of `[spanNode getAttributeNamed:@"class"]`.

Comment: here is upside down. If this "tag" not logged else logged. I'll check your suggestion.

Comment: @A-Live this Log show me `this tag 2013-04-10 14:48:44.932 GolanTelecom[98621:c07] notification-item notification-item-error`. I think because it's loop it's trying to look for this tag in all content then if it not find anything it return me false and going to else condition. But how I can search my tag inside all the content without loop? I think this is a problem. Or I need to I don't know how stop this loop when my tag is found

Comment: That actually might be the problem, use `break;` to go out of the loop .

Comment: @A-Live Thank you, that's it. I just tried right now to play with break. but your answer exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Please write the code you ended with to the answer and accept it to complete the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the working code:**

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *html = str;
    HTMLParser *parser = [[HTMLParser alloc] initWithString:html error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        return;
    }

    HTMLNode *bodyNode = [parser body];
    NSArray *spanNodes = [bodyNode findChildTags:@"div"];
    BOOL found = NO;

    for (HTMLNode *spanNode in spanNodes) {
        if ([[spanNode getAttributeNamed:@"class"] isEqualToString:@"notification-item notification-item-error"]) {
            [self alertMessageLogin];
            found = YES;
            NSLog(@"%@", [spanNode rawContents]);
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( NO == found) {
        //NSLog(@"Hey, I'm here!");
        [self HideLoginScreenWhenLogged];
    }
}
```